# How to fix number of lines to show in datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I want to display only 15 line in a datagrid and scrolling to get the rest of data. Meaning I have a datagrid Height which is variable and i want something like this 
row height = datagrid height /15.

Comment: DataGrid has `RowHeight` property. set and update it when necessary

Comment: How to display only 15 rows and the rest i can see them with scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Border` that contains a `ScrollViewer` that contains you `DataGrid`. Bind the `RowHeight` of the `DataGrid` with a `MultiBinding` to the `ActualHeight` of the `Border` and to the `ColumnHeaderHeight` of the `DataGrid`. To retrieve the value of the `RowHeight` use an `IMultiValueConverter`.

The converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace XXX
{
    public class HeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double allHeight = (double)values[0];
            double headerHeight = (double)values[1];

            return (allHeight - headerHeight) / 15;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And here the xaml:

```
  <Border Name="YourBorder">
    <ScrollViewer>
      <DataGrid Name="YourGrid"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                Padding="0"
                Margin="0"
                ColumnHeaderHeight="30">
        <DataGrid.RowHeight>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HeightConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="YourBorder"/>
            <Binding Path="ColumnHeaderHeight" ElementName="YourGrid"/>
          </MultiBinding>
        </DataGrid.RowHeight>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
          <!-- YOUR COLUMNS TEMPLATES - don't put fixed height here! -->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Border>
```

`Items`: a mock collection I've created to test this solution.

`ColumnHeaderHeight`: you MUST set this or it'll be `NaN`. I've set 30 'cause it seems suitable for a normal header text, but check it by yourself if you have custom headers.

When you stretch the window, you'll see that the rows resize, so **they always remain 15 visible** and the others remain reachable with the scrollbar.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905923/wpf-datagrid-actual-columnheaderheight) shows how to find actual headers height. I used it in exactly same situation

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution, I just added a few lines of code in datagrid_loaded event.

```
private void dataGridXX_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridXX.RowHeight = dataGridXX.RenderSize.Height / 15;
}
```

Comment: First, your solution does not work if the DataGrid has a header that occupies a portion of the height (my solution does). Second, if you resize the window, the RowHeight is not modified accordingly (my solution does).